# data table column with radio button in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to create a data table that have 4 columns with radio buttons.
I have created the data table but I am unable to get those radio buttons with the column names.

Following  is the screenshot for my requirement.
[image: Data table columns with radio buttons.]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question

Comment: @Kukeltje, Hi, Actually I need to create the GUI for the given screenshot and I just have started working on Prime faces, that's why, I have no context, how can i frame my question.

Comment: Sorry but that is not what Stackoverflow is for. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions referenced in [ask]